# How to restrict file browse in php when user is not logged in?

Tags: php, jquery

**can you explain why -1? Please dont give me any alternative suggestion..**

Im trying to implement a file upload, if the user is not logged in, then restrict the user to browse file instead show login popup.

I have tried like this:

**fileupload.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checksession()
{
    var flag_restrict;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'check_session.php',
        async: false,
        success : function(response){
            if(response === "failure")
                flag_restrict = "block";
            else
                alert("login popup code");
        }
    });
    alert(flag_restrict); //displaying nothing;

}

<input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" onclick="return checksession();">
```

**check_session.php**

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] == session_id())
{
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "failure";
}
```

Problem is when `response===failure`, file browse is opening, what am I doing wrong, what is correct way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using Ajax at all? Just test to see if they are logged in when the page with the form in it loads, then show them a login form or an upload form.

Comment: no by default i need to show browse button or drag and drop div, which is designed neatly on the home page of my website... so by default im showing up the file browse design... so can you help me on this ?

Comment: Why do you need to show users who are not logged in something that they cannot use by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `checksession` does not have a return value, it will never prevent the onclick handler to fire. The success handler of your `$.ajax()` will be executed asynchronously, as the http response from the server was received.

Things you should do (conceptually speaking):

- Only show the upload button when the user is authenticated.
- The onclick handle triggers an upload using ajax (no matter if the user is authenticated)
- The serverside upload action will return a "unauthenticated" if the user is not authenticated.
- If the upload results in a "unauthenticated" message, show the login form.

Comment: i did read your question. "what am I doing wrong?": `checksession` does never return `false`, so the dialog will always open. "what is the correct way to do this?": see my bullet points. maybe I should add: you cannot do a server call in the onclick handler to decide if the browse dialog should open or not. this is due to javascript asynchronous http handling nature.

Comment: you have to change your design. my answer describes a possible solution.

Comment: i got that requirement from my client. he just fixed for that..  *checksession* is returning false... i have tested. but as you said it is asyncronous call it is not blocking the file browse window. so im trying with async : false. but still im having the same problem

Comment: the function `checksession` from your questing does not have return statement and therefore returns nothing. `async:false` is deprecated in jquery, you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" onclick="return checksession(event);">


    function checksession(e)
{

    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'check_session.php',
    success : function(response){
                if(response === "failure")
                    e.preventDefault();
                else
                    alert("login popup code");
                }});
}
```

Comment: nope brose should not hide... just want to restrict the browser to open browse file window...

Comment: Hey.. can you confirm if you are inside the response == "failure" block

Comment: yes... if response === "failure" i need to block the browse window to open

Comment: This won't work because the moment you click on the 'browse button', there's an asynchronous event which is your ajax call taking place. This ajax call takes some time to return the request. Until the response is received, the file browser is shown. Hope this helps

Comment: i have mentioned  async: false and tried but still same problem